# SSI render web component not working using res.send() and #include virtual

Tags: javascript, express, server-side-rendering, ssi

I'm working in a project and I'm stuck in this thing. I don't know if I'm missing something or something is failing

I want to render a custom element using `Express` framework in this way:

First I have the view file where I've declared the component in this way:

**render.js** from one component

```html
<my-component><!-- # include virtual="/my-path" --></my-component>
```

Then, in another file (in another component) I'm receiving a request like this:

**server.js** from another component.

```js
app.get('/my-path', (req, res) => {
  res.send(render())
}
```

Where `render()` method return an html, for example `<div>hello</div>`.

And `my-component` is not rended by default:
**my-component.js**

```js
class WebComponent extends HTMLElement{

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connected component');
    }

}
export default WebComponent;
```

Here, my expected workflow is:

1. Load the view (render.js).
2. `my-component` call `/my-path` because the `<!-- # include virtual="/my-path" -->`
3. The component is 'filled' with `/my-path` returned HTML.
4. View the web component rendered by the server into client.

But it is not working, the component is not rendered and is empty.

I have tested accessing into `http://localhost:XXXX/my-path` and the browser output the result correctly.

Also, the custom component display the message into `console.log('connected component');`, so the component exists and starts.

But the path `my-path` is not called... why? Have I missed something or am I mistaken?. Maybe I need render the web component, but then this is not SSI rendering from the server?

Also I've manually trigger `my-path` route in the server to check if need to be called but it doesn't work either.

Edit:
I'm gonna edit to explain better:

I load web component in server side (or I think I do) in this way:

1. Build and create a `page.js` file
2. Into layout using `<script src="/my-path/page.js"></script>`
3. In `server.js` using: `app.use('/my-path', express.static('./build'));`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rendering your web component server side does not mean that your component actually runs server side. Not until it reaches the client and `customElements.define()` is called will the web component gain functionality.

Comment: I build the web component and load into layout using `<script src="/my-path/page.js"></script>` (where exists the line `customElements.define`). So is the component loaded in client side but not in server side?

Comment: No the component will not be loaded server side, as it is a client side technology. But you are able to make a HTTP request from your component and the client to `/my-path` to get the data for your component.

Answer (score 1):

The component will only work on the frontend. If it want to make a request to a certain path and use that response as the body of the element, then you can do that on the frontend.

Give your component a `path` attribute. This should be the URL to get the data from. Whenever your component has this attribute with a value it will try to get data from that path and set it as it's `innerHTML`.

```
<my-component path="/my-path"></my-component>
```

Using the `observedAttributes` and `attributeChangedCallback` methods will enable you to get new data on the first render and whenever the value of the `path` attribute is changed.

Load this component in your page. When it is rendered on the frontend it will fetch data from the value in the `path` attribute and set it as it's `innerHTML` value (as long as the request is successful).

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['path'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  get path() {    
    return this.getAttribute('path');
  }

  set path(value) {
    this.setAttribute('path', value);
  }

  async fetchPath() {
    if (!this.path) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(this.path);
      const html = await response.text();
      this.innerHTML = html;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (attrName === 'path') {
      this.fetchPath();
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test tomorrow if it works. So, `<!-- # include virtual="/my-path" -->` is not necessary/possible?

Comment: I don't know what it does, but on the frontend that comment will just be a comment.

Comment: Is a SSI directive: [example link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html).

Comment: Oh wow, I never heard of it. But that clears some things up. I was under the impression that the problem was with the component, but you're relying on SSI to render your templates. Are you using a package that makes SSI compatible with Node.js? Or have you considered using a templating engine like Jade or Handlebars to render your HTML?